# How to replace a value in multidimensional array - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a multidimensional array and I need to replace a value of a key (form_id) in it.

```
 $data = Array
    (
            [0] => Array
                  (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [form_id] => 18
                    [product_name] => test tet

                  )

            [1] => Array
                  (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [form_id] => 18
                    [product_name] => test product

                  )

         )
```

after replacing the "**form_id**" with value "**My Form**" then i need to return the whole multidimensional array. Please give me a solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't undersatand :( Do you want chnge `$data[0][form_id]`  to `$data[0][Myform]`?  or make $data[0][form_id] = MyForm ?

Comment: I need to make $data[0][form_id] = MyForm...

Comment: Why people are down voting my question ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I belive you can do that using [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Here's an (untested )example :

```
 $data = Array
    (
            [0] => Array
                  (
                    [product_id] => 1
                    [form_id] => 18
                    [product_name] => test tet

                  )

            [1] => Array
                  (
                    [product_id] => 2
                    [form_id] => 18
                    [product_name] => test product

                  )

         )
function array_replacing(&$item, $key)
{
    if($key == 'form_id')
        $item = 'myform';
}

array_walk_recursive($data, 'array_replacing');
```

Comment: Thanks mate , I have tested the code and it's working fine

Comment: I am glad that it helped you :) . Please mark it as answer if your problem is solved now.

Comment: yes, am trying to mark it, but it says "You cannot do that in 1 minute", let me try again.