# iteratively / programmatically replace a value in a multidimensional array (in Codeigniter or PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have found several purported solutions to this question, but when I try and implement them, they do not work.

```
$a = array('val'=>10, 'name'=>'Name of A', 'item3'=>'item3forA');
$b = array('val'=>20, 'name'=>'Name of B', 'item3'=>'item3forB');
$c = array('val'=>30, 'name'=>'Name of C', 'item3'=>'item3forC');
$d = array('val'=>40, 'name'=>'Name of D', 'item3'=>'item3forD');
$rlist = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

I need a way to recursively / iteratively replace the value of the 'val' key to make them all a zero (0) value.

Two of the many solutions I have tried are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719228/codeigniter-replace-array-values-in-model) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367055/how-to-replace-a-value-in-multidimensional-array-php).  I will also note if I 'explicitly' set the key to zero `$a['val']=0; $b['val']=0;` etc., that works, but I would rather set it to zero with less code (the actual program has like 20 multi-dimensional arrays to modify).

Comment: Just loop and assign. Make sure you edit the same copy of the subarray.

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does assignment by value unless explicitly instructed otherwise, so when you do

```
$rlist = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
```

The inner arrays of `$rlist` will be the *values* of `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, and `$d`, not references to those actual variables. So if you're iterating over `$rlist` and modifying its values, you will not see those changes reflected in the original `$a`, `$b`, etc. variables.

If you need that to happen, you can assign those variables to `$rlist` by reference as well as using a reference when you iterate `$rlist` as shown in the other answer.

```
$rlist = array(&$a, &$b, &$c, &$d);
```

Other possibilities you may consider based on how they fit in with the rest of your code are

- assigning the values of `$a`, etc. directly to `$rlist['a']`, etc. at the point where you're currently defining them as individual variables
- using stdClass objects (or instances of a class you define) instead of arrays, which will not need to be assigned by reference to `$rlist`

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!  :)  This $rlist modification, in conjunction with @JitendraYadav's `foreach` loop is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the reference of the given array and just set `val` = 0.

```
foreach($rlist as &$data){
  $data['val'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working.  I understand this code, and believe it _should_ work, but it just doesn't.  It should not matter if I am trying to do this within an 'if' statement, right?

Comment: I changed your question, you should define `$a, $b, $c, $d` first and then assign them to `$rlist`.

Comment: I understand your edit.  Makes sense, and that is what I am doing.  Thank you.